# Six fundamental disagreements - The Rogatchover

Tags: talmud-gemara, machlokes, rogatchover

I heard (in the name of the Rogatchover) that there are six fundamental disagreements upon which all the disagreements in Shas are based. Assuming that this is true, does anybody know what they are?

Comment: He clearly had a way of condensing knowledge into clear sections. According to this https://hakirah.org/vol15schwartz.pdf - "The Rogatchover is reported to have said that he could refine and abstract all of Torah knowledge into ten ideas!"

Comment: R. Nachman Cohen in his Encyclopedia of Talmudic Disputes follows such an approach--I believe he finds a similar number of underlying disagreements in all of the disputes of Beis Shammai and Beis Hillel